# AX QueryService 2012 "OR" query - how to?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction as to how to do an "OR" query via the Query Service?

In order to do an "AND" query I can simply add two (or more) "Ranges" - this sort of jazz:

```
        // build and add our new filter
        QueryDataRangeMetadata range = new QueryDataRangeMetadata
        {
            TableName = dataSource.Table,
            FieldName = fieldName,
            Value = fieldValue,
            Enabled = true
        };

        dataSource.Ranges[ranges.Length - 1] = range;
```

..but how does one do an "OR" ??

Comment: Also - if anyone has any tips on how to find out such info (docs I found didn't help me) - then I'd pay £1000000000000.... :-)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/02/17/calling-the-query-service/

Answer (score 3):

OR in AX queries can be made by any of these tree methods:

1. Adding another query range [on the same field](http://basicax.blogspot.dk/2012/12/x-code-to-define-or-conditions-in.html)
2. Have a range with [comma-separated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569937.aspx) values
3. Use a [query expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa893981.aspx)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12839383/4509) if the OR involves different tables.

These options should apply Query Service as well.

Answer (score 1):

...thanks for the suggestions, but in the end I don't think it's helped me much :-(

1.Adding another query range on the same field

=> unfortunately I need to query on a different field ..essentially "WHERE A=1 or B=2" type thing..

2. Have a range with comma-separated values

=> unfortunately also doesn't work with separate fields

3. Use a query expression

=> unfortunately I could not get this to work, and am coming round to the idea that it is not actually a feature the "AX Query Service 2012" (as per title) that is the tech I am working with (looks like it is something within AX??). Note that when defining a Range the "FieldName" property of the QueryDataRangeMetadata instance is required (and no - comma separated field names did not work).

On the plus side I have now got it working :-) ...the way I did it was to add the table twice as two different datasources to the query- seems nasty, but what's a man to do...

thanks again-
Oli.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past:

```
queryBuildRange.value(strFmt('((%1 == %2) || ((%1 == %3) && (%4 == "%5")))',
    fieldStr(InventTable, ItemType),
    any2int(ItemType::Service),
    any2int(ItemType::Item),
    fieldStr(InventTable, ProjCategoryId),
    queryValue("Spares")));
```

Probably is not the cleanest way to do it but will do the job.